# Page built in React that displays a grid using coldfusion within the grid there is a button to display a modal. The HTML displays but not the JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, coldfusion

I am working on a page built in React but also calls a coldfusion cfc page to display a grid. The grid HTML is generated in a cfc and then just placed on the page. This HTML and JS works just fine. Within the grid there is a button and onClick, it opens a modal (also generated HTML/JS from the same cfc) the modal opens fine and the HTML displays correctly on the page but the JS doesn't make it on the page. I'm at a loss on how to get the JS added to the page.

I am just generating an HTML string in a cfc and then appending the js to it. My assumption is I need to do something on the React end of things to have the js display on the page. I am new to React and new to working with coldfusion and React.

Happy to share some code if it's helpful but there is quite a bit of course so not sure exactly what to share. Thank you!

Comment: Did you checked the console for the JS errors?

Comment: I did and unfortunately there aren't any errors or anything like that. I'm not even seeing the js in the source code.

Comment: And I can get this code to work in a test grid that is just HTML/JS, so my assumption is it has something to do with React just not rendering the JS (because of something I'm either doing or not doing)

Comment: unfortunately it's hard to tell the exact issue without the code sample.  Could you share the sample here or in jsfiddle or CodeSandbox.

Comment: Sure, i assumed it would be difficult without code, ill see if i can share a small sample. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to update this in case anyone else runs into this issue. What ended up working for me was to create only the HTML in the cfc and append to the page. Then, in my React code, i appended an external js file.

```
componentDidUpdate(
    let externalScript2 = document.createElement("script");
      externalScript2.type = "text/javascript";
      externalScript2.src = 'js/externalJSFile.js';
      gridContainer.appendChild(externalScript2);
)
```